# Adding a space in between each tweet with the Twitter Badge

Tags: css, twitter

Looking to add a space (line break) between each individual tweet.  Here is my code so far.

```
<div id="twitter_div">
<ul id="twitter_update_list"></ul>
</div>

#twitter_div {
    float:left;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width:205px;
    height:467px;
    margin-left:11px;
    color:#e5e0bd;
    text-align:left;
    font-size:14px;
    overflow:auto;

}

#twitter_div ul {
    float:left;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    margin-left:16px;
}
```

and it looks like this http://jacobnlsn.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#twitter_div ul li {
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

Or, 14px if you want it to mirror your font-size, but 1em is equivalent to 14px in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much what davethegr8 said in his answer, but I chose also to set an explicit `line-height` and then repeat that as the `margin-bottom`, rather than using `px` sizes.

```
#twitter_div ul li {
    line-height: 1.2em;
    margin-bottom: 1.2em; /* same as line-height */
}
```